# How to remove white space above and below image in R Markdown?

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I want to export a .Rmd file primarily as a latex pdf.

This is the code that I'm currently using

````
```{r ,fig.cap="caption",fig.env='figure', fig.width=10, fig.height=10,echo=FALSE, results='asis', warning=FALSE, strip.white=TRUE}
library(png)
library(grid)
img <- readPNG("filepath/overview.png")
grid.raster(img)
```
````

As you can see, I'm already using `strip.white=TRUE` & `fig.env='figure'` but they don't seem to work. The .PNG file hasn't got any (white) spacing above or below the image.

I know I can use latex directly and achieve what I want, but I want to able to reproduce this in Word if needed. Also in Word, there's half a page empty space above and below the image.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is overview.png an exact square? If it's wider than it is tall, the height will be padded with whitespace to make it a square if you set both dimensions to 10. Try just setting fig.width.

Comment: I had a similar problem and @Pdubbs solution worked for me. Turns out I was trying to make a rectangle into a square and the result was extra white space. Thanks @Pdubbs!

Answer (score 12):

Your problem is not linked with knitr but with the raster image, which produces a white edge to keep it from being distorted. For instance, if you type `? graphics::plot.raster` you will see an `asp` argument set to 1 retain the ratio from the raster. *Plot your image in a standard R output you will see the blank parts, if you adapt the window, those white parts are removed*. So what you need is to check your image dimensions and then use a `fig.asp` ratio in knitr to produce a frame that will allow your image to fit.

## Check your image ratio

### Example using magick

```
url <- "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/11/15/20/27/diamonds-2952447_960_720.png"
image<- image_read(url)
print(image)
```

this returns

```
  format width height colorspace filesize
1    PNG   960    600       sRGB   762423
```

You can also use readPNG()

```
curl::curl_download(url, "image.png")
image <- png::readPNG("image.png",info=TRUE)
attr(image,"info")
```

From knitr [options](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/) we have the parameter `fig.asp`

> fig.asp: (NULL; numeric) the aspect ratio of the plot, i.e. the ratio
>   of height/width; when fig.asp is specified, the height of a plot (the
>   chunk option fig.height) is calculated from fig.width * fig.asp

So here we calculate `height/width`= 0.62.

## Using knitr and docx output

Here I'm using a square output passed as an `opts.label` argument *set in the first chunk*, this will amplify the problem when the image is wide.

````
--- 
title: "Crop image ?" 
output: word_document
--- 

```{r echo=FALSE}
require(knitr)
library(magick)
opts_template$set(squarefigure = list(fig.height = 6, fig.width = 6))
```
=lorem()
```{r opts.label ="squarefigure", echo=FALSE, fig.cap = "plot without setting the right raster output size"}
url <- "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/11/15/20/27/diamonds-2952447_960_720.png"
img <- image_read(url)
img%>%grid.raster()
```
=lorem()

```{r  opts.label ="squarefigure", fig.cap = "plot with correct margin, square size", fig.asp=0.62}
img%>%grid.raster()
```
=lorem()
````

As you can see the first image has a blank edge while the second is diplayed correctly.

[image: docx output]

## Using LATEX with trim

I know the answer for LATEX was not asked in the question, still if some readers
 are using knitr or sweave to produce a LATEX output then, the following 
shows how to trim an image whithin knitr. The arguments used are
`trim={<left> <lower> <right> <upper>` and the unit can be cm mm in ... (one of LATEX [unit](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Lengths) for length). To pass those arguments, you can use the `out.extra` argument in the chunk options.
Note that using the `fig.asp` argument for your image like above will work too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext

<<r1, echo=FALSE >>=
library(knitr)    
library(ggplot2)
library(magick)
# download image to disk
url <- "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/11/15/20/27/diamonds-2952447_960_720.png"
curl::curl_download(url, "image.png")
img <- image_read(png::readPNG("image.png"))
plot(img)
@

\blindtext
\newpage
\blindtext
<<r2, echo=FALSE,out.extra='trim={0 5cm 0 5cm},clip' >>=
plot(img)
@
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Using HTML

[Here](https://www.zevross.com/blog/2017/06/19/tips-and-tricks-for-working-with-images-and-figures-in-r-markdown-documents/) is an excellent blog also for understanding arguments like `fig.retina` and `out.width`

---

Finally the `strip.white` argument is to remove blank lines of code. It will not resize your image.

> strip.white: (TRUE; logical) whether to remove the white lines in the
>   beginning or end of a source chunk in the output